# NSTimer: Trying to create multiple timers with one start and one stop button

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to create a simple countdown/Up timer app for myself. So far I've figured out how to create the timers which can count up and down with a start, stop and reset buttons but I can not create a multiple timer, I'm guessing its to do with the way I'm calling the function. I'm only guessing as its my first go at it.

Variables and Labels

```
var timerCountUp = 0
var timerCountDown = 45
var timerRunning = false
var timer = NSTimer()


@IBOutlet weak var timerUpLabel: UILabel!

func CountingUp(){

    timerCountUp += 1
    timerUpLabel.text = "\(timerCountUp)"
}


@IBOutlet weak var timerDownLabel: UILabel!

func CountingDown(){

    timerCountDown -= 1
    timerDownLabel.text = "\(timerCountDown)"
}
```

Stop and Rest Buttons

```
@IBAction func stopButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if timerRunning == true{
        timer.invalidate()
        timerRunning = false
    }

}


@IBAction func restartButton(sender: UIButton) {

    timerCountUp = 0
    timerUpLabel.text = "0"

}
```

For my start button I have the following

```
 @IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if timerRunning == false{
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("CountingUp"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRunning = true

    }
```

If my selector is either "CountingUp" or "CountingDown" I get one of them to work, so I did a bit of searching and came up with the following which does not work

```
@IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if timerRunning == false{
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timerStarted"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRunning = true

    }

    func timerStarted() {

        CountingUp()
        CountingDown()
    }

}
```

Would it be possible to show me where I have gone wrong please?

Comment: Explain what happens and what you'd like to happen

Comment: In this way, the code doesn't even compile. The `timerStarted()` function should be placed outside of the `startButton:` scope.

Comment: how about checking for timer.valid ? instead of timer.running ?

Comment: What I would like to happen is when press Start if fires off two timers, one counts up and one counts down.


When I change the selector to "timerStarted" I get.
2016-02-03 15:31:45.788 Timer[3767:121524] -[Timer.ViewController fire]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf025aaf70
2016-02-03 15:31:45.813 Timer[3767:121524] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Timer.ViewController fire]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf025aaf70'